# Capturing Profisafe packets using Lua Wireshark dissector

Tags: lua, protocols, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am writing a Lua script to capture profisafe packets on wireshark.It is above the profinet layer in the stack.The wireshark dissect the profinet packets but does not dissect the profisafe.

For other protocols built on tcp or udp protocol one can do something like

```
local tcp_port = Dissector.get("tcp.port")
tcp_port:add(1234,foo_protocol)
```

to capture the packets that arises and received by the port 1234.

But profisafe is built on profinet and does not contain tcp or udp as the underlying layer.How to capture the packets in this case? I tried giving ethernet frame address in the place of port name but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the menu Edit, Preferences, Protocols and search for PNIO:
[PNIO options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eESgY.png)

Then select the checkbox "Enable detailed PROFIsafe dissection" and define a directory, where the GSDML file of the PROFIsafe device is located.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have already done this.The problem is wireshark shows the length of the profisafe data though in the GSDML file, the structure of the Profisafe data is defined. To explain further, in wireshark I view `Safety IO Data = 10` but I want to see `Safety Byte 1 value = 1e ...Safety Byte 10 value = 01`. Other parameters are correctly shown as in GSDML file.